# Trying to get user id with Auth::id() but it doesn't work in my Model?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using the passport package in my Laravel project, and I've done exactly based on Laravel Docs. When the user is logged in and I want to use `Auth::id()` in my model, it returns null.

For instance, here it works:

```
    public function like()
{
    if (!$this->favorites()->where('user_id',Auth::id())->exists()) {
        $this->favorites()->create(['user_id' => Auth::id()]);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

but here not(right below that  one):

```
    public function isFavorited()
{
    return $this->favorites()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists();
}
```

Comment: Your code says `auth()->id()`, shouldn't that be `auth()->user()->id` (note the id without brackets)

Comment: @MaartenVeerman No, `auth()->id()` is a shortcut for `auth()->user()->id`.

Comment: Quick solution from linked answer: if you're hitting a route that is not protected by the `auth:api` middleware, you'll need to specify you want the user from the `api` guard: change to `auth()->guard('api')->id()`.